# lead where string is equal

Tags: r, dplyr

my dataframe looks like this:

```
  test <-
    data.frame(
      id = c(4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15),
      dates = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-06"), "days"),
      staus = c("REGULAR", "PENDING", "ANOTHER", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING TOO")
    )
```

What I'm trying to do is get **last** PENDING or PENDING TOO status, but before another REGULAR/ANOTHER date for status REGULAR or PENDING.

In other words, result should be

```
  result <-
    data.frame(
      id = c(4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15),
      dates = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-06"), "days"),
      staus = c("REGULAR", "PENDING", "ANOTHER", "PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING TOO"),
      staus_summary = c("2019-01-02", NA, "2019-01-06", NA, NA, NA)
  )
```

Here is what I created yet, but i have an issue with possibility that not always is desired status just on next row.

```
  result <- test %>%
    mutate(
      status_summary = if_else(status %in% c("REGULAR", "ANOTHER") & lag(status) %in% c("PENDING", "PENDING TOO"), as.character(dates), NA_character_)
    )
```

Comment: sorry, i edited description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create group at every occurrence of `"REGULAR"` or `"ANOTHER"` and replace the first value in the group with the `last` `dates` value.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(staus %in% c("REGULAR", "ANOTHER"))) %>%
  mutate(staus_summary = as.Date(ifelse(row_number() == 1, 
                         last(dates), NA_real_))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#     id dates      staus      staus_summary
#   <dbl> <date>     <fct>       <date>       
#1     4 2019-01-01 REGULAR     2019-01-02   
#2     6 2019-01-02 PENDING     NA           
#3     9 2019-01-03 ANOTHER     2019-01-06   
#4    12 2019-01-04 PENDING     NA           
#5    14 2019-01-05 PENDING     NA           
#6    15 2019-01-06 PENDING TOO NA
```